# Uploading pictures in Django fields and calling that file in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, upload

My name is Luca and this is my first post,
I've been working on a little project lately.
I solve flight deals for people and would like to upload a screenshot for every deal I solve so that the client can see on his unique url the screenshot.
What is the line of code that I have to insert so I can add a screenshot and what is the line I have to insert in my html that I have to insert so that it is linked to that file specifically?

in my models I have

```
from django.db import models
import random

 def deal_get_code():
    code = ''.join(random.choice('abcdef0123456789') for i in range(16))
 while Deal.objects.filter(code=code).exists():
    code = ''.join(random.choice('abcdef0123456789') for i in range(16))
 return code

 class Deal(models.Model):

     code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16, default=deal_get_code)

#all my fields and their attributes ex:
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
#etc

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.code, self.name)
```

And then in my HTML I have

```
<div>Dear, your flight will depart on the: {{ deal.departure_date }} 
 Your flight will return on the: {{ deal.return_date }} </div>
```

etc etc.. 
If I'm not wrong I should insert a line in models like this

If i'm not wrong, I have to create a field

```
screenshot_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/home/xx/xxx/screenshots/')
screenshot_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/home/xx/xxx/screenshots/')     
screenshot_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/home/xx/xxx/screenshots/')
```

What else do I have to add (other files) and what should I put in the html for it to always retrieve the new file I just uploaded?

It would be terrific if you could help me!

Thank you so much, 
All the best

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <a target="_blank" href="{{deal.screenshot_1.url}}">
```

will give you the path of the file in the template

Comment: It tells me I should add something in url and views,
It also tells me that models.ImageField does not exist and I tried then to change it to models.FileField
Could you redirect me?

Comment: please attach the screenshot of the error you are getting